# Major Difference between sharedpreference and internal file storage

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to know which is better for storage purpose:
Shared preferences or internal file storage.
Which is faster?
Is there any memory issue with anyone of them?

Thanks,

Comment: why don't you make a test to see which one is faster? and regarding memory issues, if your code is good, you won't have any issues with any of both methods

Answer (score 14):

- **SharedPreference:** Store private primitive data in key-value pairs. (To store small entries/data)
- **Internal Storage:** Store private data on the device memory. (To store large datasets)

More about Storage Options here: [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

I have seen an issue about shared preference.

Issue:
Whenever you face Force close/app crash while using SharedPreference, SharedPreference will be null. Here you can read more about it: [Shared Preferences reset when the app is force closed or crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4801074/shared-preferences-reset-when-the-app-is-force-closed-or-crashes)

Comment: +1. Good Answer. I have a question. Can Shared Preferences's XML file be exported and view by somebody having the phone? I ask this because I intend to store the current user's username and password in the shared preferences

Comment: @Ashwin check: (getSharedPreferences with MODE_PRIVATE)[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)]

Comment: MODE_PRIVATE says that other applications cannot access the shared preference. But can I connect my phone to the PC and go to DDMS(Eclipse) and from there export this file to the PC. (It is possible to do so for DATABASE - DB can be exported to the PC)

Answer (score 3):

Well, the `Shared preferences` also saved in the `internal file storage` at last.

the `Share preferences` like the `key-value` pair, it keep the data in memory, and saved to the internal file storage by system at last.

> if you want to access the value frequently, you can use `Shared
>   preferences`.
>
> if you data structure is small and not complicated, you can directed
>   use `Share preferences`
>
> if you just want to save data, and the data is will taken many memory
>   space, you can just use file to save.

Comment: Can Shared Preferences's XML file be exported and view by somebody having the phone? I ask this because I intend to store the current user's username and password in the shared preferences.

Answer (score 1):

Please read [Android document](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) related to data storage.

If you want to store very small values then you can opt for SharedPrefrence.

Answer (score 0):

It totally depends on what you like to do: If you have a rather small amount of key-value pairs go with the Shared Preferences. If you have a larger amount of data use a file as the Shared Preferences will be hold in memory after they where first used. So it's a bad idea to store large amount of data in it ;-).