# Clearing Intent when DO NOT KEEP ACTIVITY is ON

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an Activity which will auto redirect to another activity when the intent has the data. A simple snippet as below

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String mykey = intent.getStringExtra("MyKey");

    if (mykey != null) {
        intent.removeExtra("MyKey");
        Intent sendingIntent = new Intent(this, targetActivity.class);
        sendingIntent.putExtra("Next Key", mykey);
        startActivity(sendingIntent);
    }
}
```

I put this in `onCreate()`, so that if it ever returns to this activity (e.g. user push a back button from the targetActivity), this will not be called, and it will not auto redirect to targetActivity again.

However, in the event of DO NOT KEEP ACTIVITY is turned on (for testing scenario where activity is killed), the onCreate is always called. And the Intent get back the original value set by its Caller, and redirection continue to happen.

So I thought I could remove the Intent after used. Referring to [Clearing intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4116110/clearing-intent), it is stated that to clear the intent (or the extra of the intent), use

```
        intent.removeExtra("MyKey");
```

This seems only work in normal case, but not when DO NOT KEEP ACTIVITY is turned on.

Hence my question is, is there a way to ensure that the Intent is only used once upon entering the activity, and got cleared? i.e. When the user return to the activity (back button pushed), regardless of if it is resume or restarted (i.e.DO NOT KEEP ACTIVITY is on), the intent (or it's extra) should be cleared.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is when the intent is called it is always passed with "MyKey" and when Do not keep is enabled the intent tends to get called with the same data over again hence the transition always happens. **One solution could be using Shared Preferences or some persistent storage like File and SQLlite** but these will be very slow as it involve disk operations and of course are inefficient when the application switches a lot back and forth to this intent.

Comment: Good explanation, thanks! Up vote your answer. Yes, that's the workaround I'm using currently using i.e. sharedPreferences. Would be really interested to see if there's any smart workaround to get the intent used once and cleared.

Comment: Just a bit of clarification needed.. you want to keep track of that even after the application is killed or only when this particular intent is cleared?

Comment: Though SharedPreferences is neat workaround! as they are kept in memory during the application scope, so the performance is pretty much same as intent data. They are read from the disk once the application is started after being killed or restarted so the application start time might be a bit slower it really very small difference. There is an **ISSUE with SharedPreferences** please have a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11222499/share-preferences-or-internal-file-storage-any-memory-issue) for details.

Comment: Thanks Mubashir. What I want is if user went back to the activity, it will not automatically redirect again even if the activity is restarted (like in the case of DONT KEEP ACTIVITY). Shared Preference is not ideal for my case but it's the best workaround I had for now.

Answer (score 0):

If you need this type of navigation, the safest way to do this is to override the BACK button in the other Activity, so that pressing it doesn't perform the standard behaviour (ie: call `finish()` which then removes that Activity from the stack and drops the user back into your dispatcher Activity), but instead does this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // Instead of just calling finish(), we want to explicitly
    //  redirect back to dispatcher activity and make sure that it doesn't redirect back here
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DispatcherActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This should do what you want, even when "DO NOT KEEP ACTIVITIES" is enabled.

Comment: Thanks David. Sounds like a good 'hack' option if shared-preference approach doesn't meet my need. Would need to explain my code reviewer and convince them :P